# Como posso fazer para pegar o insert no log com usuário logado ? Identity - Asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Preciso obter o usuário logado, para fazer um insert no log, assim, incluindo qual usuário incluiu na tabela, fez alteração, e o delete.
Estou aprendendo a linguagem, e ainda tenho muitas dúvidas.

Este é o meu controller do AccountController:

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Porém como posso fazer, para pegar o usuário logado, para fazer o insert no log ? 
Se fosse em um webforms, ou winforms, eu teria a tabela log, e faria o insert, logo após a ação do usuário. 
Seria desta mesma forma? E como pegar o id e o nome do usuário que está logado, para fazer o insert em todas as páginas? 
Além do log, preciso incluir em algumas tabelas, o usuário que fez a ação também, como fazer isso ?

Edit:
Esta é a forma que faz o login:

```
  public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;


    public LoginModel(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        ApplicationDbContext db, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _db = db;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);

                //var count = _db.ShoppingCart.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == user.Id).ToList().Count;
                //HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("CartCount", count);
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(Url.GetLocalUrl(returnUrl));
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Edit: Eu fiz assim:
Adicionei está linha no controller da page:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
```

E estou tentando pegar o id do usuário assim:

```
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        Id = user.Id;
```

Ele me retorna este erro:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Nesta linha:

```
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

Edit:
Controller é este:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `UserManager` para pegar o usuário atual, seu código ficaria assim:

```
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
private readonly ILogger _logger;
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public AccountController(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    _logger = logger;
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> FazAlgumaCoisa()
{
    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Desta maneira você tem o `ApplicationUser` e seu `Id`

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80104/discussion-on-answer-by-barbetta-como-posso-fazer-para-pegar-o-insert-no-log-com)

Answer (score 2):

Na sua classe Startup, no método ConfigureServices, verifique se existe uma linha assim, caso não exista, adicione:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

No seu controller, adicione no construtor (se não existir) o parâmetro para o HttpContextAccessor e um UserManager, crie um atributo do tipo ApplicationUser no seu controller e faça isso:

```
public Controller(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
    var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpUser.User;
    var getUserTask = userManager.GetUserAsync(user);
    getUserTask.Wait();

    User = getUserTask.Result;
}
```

Se você quiser alguma informação específica, existem os métodos síncronos como GetUserId, GetUserName, etc, vale a pena olhar a [documentação oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: No caso ai eu pego o nome né? Preciso pegar o Id. Desta forma aqui eu pego o nome, como passo pra pegar o id?      string nome = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;

Comment: Com esse objeto você tem acesso a todas as informações do usuário, id, nome, email, telefone, etc

Comment: Você pode carregar os dados individualmente com o userManager.GetUserName(user) ou userManager.GetUserId(user)