# Pegar ID do User Entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou tentando pegar o id do usuário e salvar na tabela, aqui está como eu referenciei na tabela a ForeignKey:

```
public string FuncionarioId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FuncionarioId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

E aqui é como estou tentando jogar para a tabela:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var CR = _context.ContasReceber.Find(ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.Id);
            CR.Quitado = true;
            CR.ValorPago = Convert.ToDecimal(ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.ValorPago.ToString().Replace(",","."));
            CR.FormaPagamento = ContasReceberVM.ContasReceber.FormaPagamento;
            CR.DataPagamento = DateTime.Now;
            ApplicationUser a = new ApplicationUser();
            CR.FuncionarioId = a.Id;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            Message = "Pagamento Realizado com Sucesso!";

            return RedirectToPage("Index");
        }
    }
```

Porém desta forma, ele não pega o ID correto, ele pega um ID que não existe, ai me retorna o seguinte erro.

> A instrução UPDATE conflitou com a restrição do FOREIGN KEY "FK_ContasReceber_AspNetUsers_FuncionarioId". O conflito ocorreu no banco de dados "CronoParque", tabela "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
>    A instrução foi finalizada.

Ele retorna este erro, porque o ID não confere com o ID cadastrado na tabela AspNetUsers.

Comment: O código do `_context.ContasReceber` está em 1 controller? poderia adicionar a action toda na pergunta?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, ela está no controller da page edit, criada pela page razor.

Comment: Você não consegue pegar o ID do usuário assim: User.Identity.GetUserId(); ?

Comment: @GustavoSantos não, ele me retorna este erro, quanto tento desta forma: "IIdentity" não contém uma definição para "GetUserId" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "GetUserId" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "IIdentity"

Comment: Você precisa importar Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IdentityExtensions para usar esse método

Comment: Já uso, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

Comment: Você está dando um `new` no `ApplicationUser` isso vai gerar um novo ID, você precisa recuperar o usuário atual, como respondido na pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313280/como-posso-fazer-para-pegar-o-insert-no-log-com-usuário-logado-identity-asp

Comment: Me parece que você precisa fazer `CR.ApplicationUser  = a;` ao invés de `CR.FuncionarioId = a.Id;`. Quando você cria um novo `ApplicationUser` o Id não existe. Só vai existir depois do `SaveChanges`.